# micro_out: protoc-gen-micro: Plugin failed

Tags: go, go-micro

I am trying out go-micro and I have issues genearating `.micro` boilerplate code. I have set my env and even passed the direct directory of my `GOPATH` but got error

> /Users/Olar/home/golib/bin/protoc-gen-micro: program not found or is
>   not executable Please specify a program using absolute path or make
>   sure the program is available in your PATH system variable
>   --micro_out: protoc-gen-micro: Plugin failed with status code 1.

the command I run

```
protoc --plugin=protoc-gen-go=/Users/Olar/home/golib/bin/protoc-gen-go --plugin=protoc-gen-micro=/Users/Olar/home/golib/bin/protoc-gen-micro --proto_path=/Users/Olar/home/golib/src:. --go_out=. --micro_out=. greeter.proto
```

on removal of `--micro_out=.`, `greeter.pb.go` file is generated but the `.micro` is not generated. How can I fix this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have `protoc` and the plugin (`protoc-gen-micro`) installed.

I think you omitted the second step.

See:

https://github.com/micro/protoc-gen-micro

And perhaps:

```sh
go get github.com/micro/protoc-gen-micro
```

And then:

```sh
which protoc-gen-micro
```

Comment: `which protoc-gen-micro`
protoc-gen-micro not found

Comment: I opened another terminal and did `go get ...` then I got this error

`package github.com/micro/protoc-gen-micro/v2: cannot find package "github.com/micro/protoc-gen-micro/v2" in any of:
 /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.14/libexec/src/github.com/micro/protoc-gen-micro/v2 (from $GOROOT)
 /Users/Olar/home/golib/src/github.com/micro/protoc-gen-micro/v2 (from $GOPATH)`

Comment: I just tried it and `go get github.com/micro/protoc-gen-micro` (omit the `/v2`) works for me and I can then `ls `${GOPATH}/bin/protoc-gen-micro` and `protoc` should then work

Comment: go get github.com/micro/protoc-gen-micro
go: module github.com/micro/protoc-gen-micro: git ls-remote -q origin in /Users/user1/go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/28cfbca4f5e41691076780b2017d5a1000b007b1d3d37b7a9d3b562c7adc9377: exit status 128:
 remote: Repository not found.
 fatal: repository 'https://github.com/micro/protoc-gen-micro/' not found

Answer (score 0):

l find protoc-gen-micro is under this :https://github.com/go-micro/generator, you can download it to local project and use it

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).